# Reduce number of logging libraries in project

Tags: java, logging

Project, I am working on, is using several open source frameworks. Each framework uses some logging library. 
My problem is that final deliverable contains log4j (in two different versions), slf4j with logback and of course common logging. 
I am looking for solution how to reduce number of libraries, can I exclude logging libraries in maven's pom file and configure slf4j to 'intercept' logging messages?

Answer (score 4):

Slf4j has some information in [its manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) about how to do some of this.

I think what you are looking for is to exclude `log4j` and `commons-logging` from all of your maven dependencies and load the [`log4j-over-slf4j`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.slf4j%7Clog4j-over-slf4j%7C1.6.4%7Cjar) and the [`jcl-over-slf4j`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.slf4j%7Cjcl-over-slf4j%7C1.6.4%7Cjar) packages instead.  They are designed to replace the `log4j` and `commons-logging` and contains the appropriate `org.apache.log4j` and `org.apache.commons.logging` classes to replace `Logger`, `Log`, and friends.  This won't cut down on the libraries but it will put all of the log output through `sl4fj`.  Unless you get rid of the usage of these classes (obviously) you can't reduce the dependency on either the `slf4j` wrapper or the original.

If you are instead looking to use one logging package then the right way to do it might instead to switch to use `commons-logging` which is designed as a logging delegator and then use the `slf4j-jcl` package which hooks into `commons-logging`.

For posterity, you exclude the dependency this way for each of the dependencies that requires `log4j`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>.../groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Check this out](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html)

**EDIT** read your question a bit more closely. slf4j adds a legacy bridge for non slf4j projects. But you will still need to supply the dependent jars on your runtime path. Its just the cost of not repeating someone else's work.

I mean think about it you have all those fully qualified symbols that essentially need linked in your jvm. Nothing short of some straight voodoo is going to get you around including the dependent libraries.

Comment: The problem does not concern my logging, I am using log4j. Other logging libraries comes with 3-party libraries. Can I configure slf4j to listen and capture other's logging messages?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [pax-logging](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxlogging/Pax+Logging). It brings in pretty much all the logging framework interfaces you can think of (right package names and classes, etc...) *but* it doesn't implement them. Instead, it links those facades to a log4j backend.

In other words, your projects continue using their original logging frameworks, but these are (transparently) handed over to a log4j. This way your logging output is consistent, and configured only in one place.